# Adding node to a sorted tree store

Tags: sorting, gwt, gxt

Firstly I'm using GXT 3.1.1 with GWT 2.6.1

I have a TreeStore which displays the items at a TreeGrid component and it is sorted like below:

```
 //Sort the list alphabetically     
    treeStore.addSortInfo(new StoreSortInfo<BaseTreeGridDTO>(comparator, SortDir.ASC));
```

However, once it is already sorted and I add new elements to it, they are always placed at the end of the list.

Is there any way to add these new items to this sorted TreeStore where it can keep the alphabetical order?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you set SortInfo for a TreeStore, this will not work. You have to set for a ListStore.

For example, instead of using grid.getTreeStore(), use grid.getStore().

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried to call:

```
treeStore.applySort(true);
```

after you added the item to the store?

Comment: Hi Hoss,

I did tried that but it does NOT work :/

I don't know if it is a bug or if I need to do something else before or after calling this method.

Comment: Have you checked if your comarator is ok?

Comment: Everything looks alright. I'm saying it is alright because when there is no filter applied to the treeStore, it works. In other words, when no filters is applied and I add a new element to the store that element is placed in the right spot alphabetically.